# Why does Express onError handler only handle "listen" errors?

Tags: node.js, express

The Express generator defines an `onError()` [event handler](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/master/templates/js/www.ejs#L57) that has this:

```
if (error.syscall !== 'listen') throw error;
```

The `syscall` is described as "[a string describing the syscall that failed](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_syscall)", of which there are [many possible types of failures](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (on linux, not sure what would happen on windows).

So why is only a "listen" error handled - surely the node app can fail for other reasons? This is part of the express generator template, I'm sure there's a good reason for it.